# How do Join and Get back results in sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Based on the following tables(Table1 and Table2) structure. I would like to get a Table3. How can I do this in Sql Server ?

Table1

```
ID Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Table2

```
ID Name
1  D
2  E
```

Expected Output is

```
ID Name
1   D
2   E
3   C
```

Comment: please tell me relation between first and second table

Comment: Based on what? The data in table2 if it exists, otherwise table1 based on id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE` with an outer join

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
       COALESCE(t2.Name, t1.Name)AS Name 
FROM   table1 t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
               ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8640/1/0) (with insert into `Table3`)

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
Table1.ID,case when Table2.Name is null then Table1.Name else Table2.Name end
from
Table1 left join Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id
```

Your data are not too many and i'm not sure if that's what you want. For your example, i think it works

Comment: I prefer `COALESCE` to `CASE`

Comment: maybe because of using. i'll change "using (id)' to "table1.id=table2.id"

Comment: True, COALESCE is much better. CASE is just simpler to understand

Comment: using (id) is used in Postgres. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

select t1.id,t2.name from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id

I hope this will produce the result like

```
t1.id  t1.name  t2.id  t2.name
1       A        1       D
2       B        2       E
3       C        NULL    NULL
```